# How to switch to the first fragment when selecting an item from the recyclerView of second Fragment? Both fragments are in tablayout with viewPager2

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, audio-player

[image: strong text]

When I click an item from the SongList fragment, it should automatically switch to the NowPlaying fragment. Also how will I send the item position of the selected song from the recyclerView of the SongList fragment to the NowPlaying fragment? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Access your NavController in your Fragment with `getParentFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_view)` and call `.navigate(R.id.now_playing)`.